# iteration over vector with push_back calls on it

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

So my question is a bit strange, it relates to vector modification while iterating on it in a for loop.
Example:

```
  //Declare
  std::vector<int> a{4,6,1,9} ;
  std::vector<int> b{-1000,-2000,-3000,-4000} ;

  //Allocate sufficient cap 
  a.reserve(100) ;

  // helpers
  int max = 0 ;
  int min ;
  int condition = 1 ; 

  //Loop
  while(condition){
    min = max ;
    max = a.size() ;

    for(int i = min; i < max ; i++){
      for(int j : b){
        a.push_back( a[i] + j ) ;
      }
    }
  //Cut out elements from previous state
  a.erase(a.begin(),a.begin() + max) ;

    //..... operations that might cause condition = 0 
  }
```

My idea is to use the same vector to house an unknown number of results from operations done on elements from the previous state of the vector. Here we can calculate in advance how many inputs will be added, but in my original problem I will not know- i.e vector `a` can have any number (within capacity) of initial elements inside it before the loop starts, and Also there might be a conditional statement just before `a.push_back( a[i] + j ) ;` which might cause some of the `a.push_back( a[i] + j ) ;` operations to be skipped.  Essentially this is kind of a vectorised recursion.

My question is whether or not this can result in undefined behavior, and whether this kind of sequence reallocates memory even though capacity in the `a` vector should be sufficient at all stages.

Comment: Just fyi, no UB that I can see. You're already doing it correctly (with indexes and `operator []` and/or `at`). The wheels would fall off the wagon had you been using ranged-for or actual iterators.

Comment: Yeah I sat on it for a while to make sure that it makes sense, its supposed to be a recursive vector loop. thanks for the input @WhozCraig

Comment: Iv'e just realized I had a mistake, if I use `max` and `min` I dont have to erase the elements from the previous loop. I guess its possible to trade, either accept larger memory usage by not using erase , or use erase and have aditional operations but significantly smaller  maximum capacity requirements